# Why can I declare a float in a header file, but not a custom struct type?

Tags: c++

Why can I declare a float like:

> Player.h (compiles)

```
#include "Component.h"
#include "Vector2.h"

class Player : public Component
{
public:
    float positionX;
    float positionY;
};
```

but can't declare a my Vector2 struct like:

> Player.h (does not compile)

```
#pragma once

#include "Component.h"
#include "Vector2.h"

class Player : public Component
{
public:
    Vector2 position;
};
```

> Vector2.h

```
#pragma once

struct Vector2
{
    Vector2(float t_x, float t_y);

    float x;
    float y;
};
```

> Vector2.cpp

```
#include "Vector2.h"

Vector2::Vector2(float t_x, float t_y)
{
    x = t_x;
    y = t_y;
}
```

I'm new to C++ so I might be doing something completely wrong, but I don't know what. I just want to declare a variable of type Vector2 to use inside of my Player.cpp file.

Comment: Re: “does not compile” — surely the compiler gave you more information than that. What was the error message?

Comment: I expect a compiler error about `Vector2` not having a suitable constructor, since you didn't define a default constructor

Comment: Creating a `Vector2` object requires one of its constructors to be called. By adding a custom constructor, you prevented the default (aka parameter-less) constructor from being generated. Either add a default constructor, or provide an initializer, e.g. `Vector2 position = Vector2(1, 2);`, or create a constructor for `Player` and inititialzie the `position` in its member init list.

Comment: I advise to remove `Vector2(float t_x, float t_y);`. Vector2 will be aggregate with a possible aggregate initializing like Vector2 vec{1, 2}, that is the same as with the custom constructor. Additionally you may default initialize `float x = 0;` and `float y = 0;`

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Vector2 doesn't have a parameter-less constructor, C++ won't know how to construct it.

You need to declare how to construct your Vector2 in the Player constructor using parameter initialization, like so:

```
Player::Player() : position(0,0) {
    // player initialization here
}
```

Another option is to store an std::unique_ptr to your Vector2, leaving the initialization of the Vector2 at runtime.

Comment: Or change member variable `Vector2 position;` to `Vector2 position = Vector2{0, 0};`